# iframe.contentWindow on IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have an  element on page:

```
<iframe vspace="0" hspace="0"
    style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;word-wrap:break-word;border:0px;"
    id="some-iframe"></iframe>
```

and I'm trying to get contentWindow property of this frame using the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById('some-iframe').contentWindow
```

It's ok under at least FF, Opera, Chrome, but under IE8 I get:

```
>>> document.getElementById('some-iframe').contentWindow
[ ]
```

What's there wrong and how do I get contentWindow object under IE8?

Comment: What does `alert` ing say it is? Prefixed by `typeof`? An object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid I, the "problem" is solved, `[]` is just FireBug Lite strange behavior.